# How can I replace setTimeOut by something better in addListener?

Tags: jquery, async-await

I am working on Google Maps-related functionality where I am updating certain pins on map `dragend`, `zoom_changed`, `center_changed`. The pins collection might be 0, 1, 2, or more.

I am using setTimeOut something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, "dragend", function () {
  self.saveMapConfig();
  setTimeout(loopThroughPins(self.map), 400);
});
```

I have gone through `async`, `await` related solutions but I am a little bit confused how can I apply here in this case as I am calling two functions on the dragend event.

The drawback of setTimeOut is when I don't need to wait still it waits because of the time given to wait.

**Please help me with the possible solution.** Thanks!

Adding additional code for reference:

```
        function loopThroughPins( map ) {
            //setTimeout(function(){
                if( 12 <= map.getZoom()) {
                    // Update POI list
                    var $poiSelectedVal = $('#point_of_interest_select').val();
                    $('#point_of_interest_select').prop('disabled',false);
                    poiMarkers.forEach( function( item, index){
                        var $poiSelectElement = '#poi_' + index;
                        if( map.getBounds().contains(poiMarkers[index].getPosition()) ) {
                            $($poiSelectElement).show();
                        } else {
                            $($poiSelectElement).hide();
                        }

                    });
                    setPointsOfInterest($poiSelectedVal, map);
                } else {
                    console.log('hide all POIs');
                    poiMarkers.forEach( function( item, index){
                        poiMarkers[index].setMap(null);
                    });
                    $('#point_of_interest_select').prop('disabled',true);

                }
            //}, 400);
            filterPlaces(map);
        }

        // Filter Places
        function filterPlaces( map ){
            //setTimeout(function(){
                if( 12 <= map.getZoom() ) {
                    // Places Markers
                    if( !placeMarkers.length ) {
                        var placeValue = ppConfig.apartment_search_google_place_default_on;
                        if( 'undefined' !== typeof placeValue ) {
                            getPlaces([placeValue], map);
                        }
                    } else {
                        showHidePlaceMarkers(map, 1);
                    }
                    $('.top-places-container').show();
                } else {
                    showHidePlaceMarkers(map, 0);
                    $('.top-places-container').hide();

                }
            //}, 400);
        }

        function setPointsOfInterest( $poiSelectedVal, map ){
            if( "" == $poiSelectedVal ) {
                poiMarkers.forEach( function( item, index) {
                    poiMarkers[index].setMap(map);
                });
            } else {
                poiMarkers[$poiSelectedVal].setMap(map);
            }
        }
```

Comment: 'Drawback of setTimeOut is when I don't need to wait still it waits because of the time given to wait.' Under what condition do you not need to wait? You need to write some code to recognise that condition, then either use the `setTimeout()` or invoke `loopThroughPins()` directly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I mean to say this will be dynamic and depends on the DOM load / Network speed, etc. And the number of pins might be 10, 50, or 100 so it is difficult to give a specific time to wait. Instead what I am looking for is when the JOB is done ( loopThroughPins call ) then execute the next code/flow.

Comment: In that case return a promise from `loopThroughPins()` which you can chain code from. If you need additional help with this, please add the code of `loopThroughPins()` to the question, as that's what needs to be changed.

Comment: Added the function definition of `loopThroughPins()` which is again having other function calls.